# Do I always need to inject $location to use it in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using angular declarations without using or injecting `$scope` var, but with `this.` declarations

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('myCtrl', myCtrlFunction); 
                   
     function myCtrlFunction() {
        this.myUrl = "This is myUrl content";
     }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <p>Here I put my var myUrl:</p>
    <h3>{{vm.myUrl}}</h3>
</div>
```

It works ok but I can't figure out how to access '$location' so this works after minification

```js
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
         app.controller('myCtrl', myCtrlFunction); 
                       
         function myCtrlFunction() {
            this.myUrl = $location.absUrl();
         }
```

```html
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
        <p>Here I put my var myUrl:</p>
        <h3>{{vm.myUrl}}</h3>
    </div>
```

Do I need to change the way I declare the contents of `myCtrlFunction()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because it has dependency injection. In your current setup, your controller requires $location to be a global variable. Also, you need to supply a an array with string values for the parameter names, so angular still knows what to inject after the parameters are changed by minification algorithms.

So, use either one of those setups:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', ['$location', myCtrlFunction]); 

function myCtrlFunction($location) {
    this.myUrl = "This is myUrl content";
}
```

or:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', myCtrlFunction); 

function myCtrlFunction($location) {
    this.myUrl = "This is myUrl content";
}
// tell angular what parameters are expected
myCtrlFunction.$inject = ['$location'];
```

[More about dependency injection in Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

Comment: Thank you! 

The injection of `myCtrlFunction.$inject = ['$location'];` must be after `myCtrlFunction($location)` or that doesn't matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject $location.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('myCtrl', myCtrlFunction); 

     function myCtrlFunction(**$location**) {
        this.myUrl = $location.absUrl();
     }
```

You got away with the previous version because you weren't actually using the $scope keyword. But with $location you are specifically using it, so you need to inject it.